# What is the opposite of max.col()

Tags: r

I want a function that does the opposite of `max.col()` (which would be min.col)

There is an answer for this, but I don´t really understand it. Could anybody give a different solution?

Comment: `max.col(-x)` would be the equivalent of `min.col(x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negate the columns. Using `BOD` which comes with R:

```
max.col(BOD)
## [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2

max.col(-BOD)
## [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

If the data frame is not numeric use `xtfrm` first

```
DF <- data.frame(X = c("a", "b", "a"), Y = c("b", "a", "b"))
max.col(-t(apply(DF, 1, xtfrm)))
## [1] 1 2 1
```